# PHP - Magento - pager.phtml - addAttributeToFilter

Tags: php, magento

I'm having some trouble to get the pager working as I want in Magento.

The problem is:

I'm getting a product collection in which I'm filtering products with images only.

But the pagination still shows the total count of products without the filtering applied, how can I solve this?

Example:
      I got 38 products, only 23 of them have images associated, if I define to display 9 products by page it should present 1|2|3. But it still shows the 1|2|3|4|5.

Thanks in advance, and bellow is the piece of code I'm using to filter the products.

```
 $_productCollection = clone $this->getLoadedProductCollection()
       ->clear()
       ->addAttributeToFilter('small_image', array('neq' => 'no_selection'))
       ->load();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you need to include addAttributeToSelect:

```
$_productCollection = clone $this->getLoadedProductCollection()
->clear()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('image', array('neq' => 'no_selection'));
```

**EDIT 1**

ok, than you need to go into the file `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php` and try to edit the method `getProductCollection()` from:

```
public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
            ->addCategoryFilter($this);
        return $collection;
    }
```

into:

```
public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
            ->addAttributeToFilter('small_image', array('neq' => 'no_selection'))
            ->addCategoryFilter($this);
        return $collection;
    }
```

of course, you should not edit it directly, then to override in you local pool. Than your code with cloning can be deleted.

Comment: thanks but that didn'fixed the problem. Any other suggestion?